# Programmatically build / navigate a Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

Before:

My App is based on indepent view controllers. I can switch from one to another by replacing the root view controller on the application delegate:

```
ade.window.rootViewController = newController;
```

... and all worked right, till now.

Tomorrow:

we have to add a NavigationController-based part of our App, which will help the users navigate through our:

Brands => Model Names => Colors

So, the user will choose a color, then click a button: now I will switch to another UIViewController (call it "pippo"), which actually resides outside that navigation hierarchy (I can't push it in the nav-controller for several methods, I'm forced doing so!).

What I want is to get back to my "Color" screen, from "pippo". So, I'm looking for a way to programmatically "navigate" the navigation controller I restore, I mean:

- I restore my navigation controller
- now I'm on Brands, but I don't want my users to be here, I want to show them the last color they was on (I saved it in the preferences)
- how can I simulate the selection of a known brand and model?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `applicationDidFinishLoading` in App delegate:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];
[window addSubview:navController.view];
```

That will instantiate the navigation controller and add it to the window as a view.

Now, in your rootViewController class (lets say its called `FirstViewController`) you can do this:

```
- (void)clickedAButton:(id)selector {
  SecondViewController *nextViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  // and push it onto the 'navigation stack'
  [self.navigationController pushNavigationController:nextViewController animated:YES];
  // and release
  [nextViewController release];
}
```

And in your `SecondViewController` you can navigate back through the stack using:

```
- (void)clickedAnotherButton:(id)selector {
  // goes back to the last view controller in the stack
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

So for you it would go:

Set up navigation controller in the app delegate with `Brand` as the root view controller
User chooses their brand and you `pushViewController:animated:` the `Model` view controller. Then the user chooses their model and you `pushViewController:animated:` the `Color` view controller. Similarly the user chooses a color and you push the `Pippo` view controller. Now, if the user presses back (or you call `popViewControllerAnimated:`) it will go back to the `Color` view controller in the same state as when the user left it to go to the `Pippo` controller.

Comment: soorry, wrong answer for two reasons: i quote from my post: ""pippo"), which actually resides outside that navigation hierarchy (I can't push it in the nav-controller for several methods, I'm forced doing so!)." So you know that I CAN'T and I DON'T WANT to push 'pippo' in my navigation controller. - in addition, I want to navigate the controller WITHOUT user interaction. :-\

Comment: I can't think  of a single scenario where you can't push a viewcontroller onto a navigation stack. However, you're the boss. Navigating the stack without user interaction is possible using the methods push and pop. Anyway, can't help you, as I don't really understand anymore.

Comment: My 'pippo' is a custom imagepicker, a photo camera. However I'll try to push my brand and model view controller without animation and see what it does.

Comment: Ok cool. You can add your own animations by using UIView animation around where you `pushViewController:animated:`

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code in AppDelegate.m Class

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
   MainViewController *mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
    self.nav.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [mainViewController release];
   [_window addSubview:nav.view];
   [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
 }
```