# add navigation controller to viewcontroller which is the rootviewcontroller of the window

Tags: iphone, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, xib

I want to add navigation controller to view controller which is the rootviewcontroller of the window. Two xib files main window.xib and view controller.xib files.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

tried this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

 [self.window addSubview:self.navController.view];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

but not working i think as there are two xib files involved.

Comment: have you tried this.......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241923/programmatically-build-navigate-a-navigation-controller

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the root view controller correctly. You are close though. Here is the right code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];


self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```